# Checkbox and CheckAll button for Cell in UItableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a tableView with a variable number of cells representing for objects

and I have a checkbox button con each cell, when I click on it it will show the hidden button which allow me to delete the object, and I'm also have the "checkall" button to choose all the cells

I'm stucking at I can make the checkall button choose all cell and show the "Delete Button" but not with each cell, here is my code and appearance, thanks for your helps.

///cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ContractCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContractTBVCell

    cell.selected = isCheckedAll

   return cell
}
```

///////Checkall button func

```
var isCheckedAll = false
@IBAction func selectAllAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    isCheckedAll = !isCheckedAll
    self.selectAllBtn.selected = isCheckedAll

    if(selectAllBtn.selected == true) {
        self.deleteReqBtn.hidden = false
        self.deleteReqBtn.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    if (selectAllBtn.selected == false){
        self.deleteReqBtn.hidden = true
        self.deleteReqBtn.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

}
[image]

[image]